# Using NLog to log to MySql database using Pomelo provider in an ASP .Net Core 5 Web API

Tags: .net-core, nlog, .net-5, mysql-connector, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have an ASP .Net Core Web API using NLog, and I am trying to configure it to log to a MySQL database. I am using Pomelo in my app to talk to MySql.

In the nlog.config file, I have:

```
    <target name="db"
        xsi:type="Database"
        dbProvider="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore"
        connectionString="blah blah blah"
        commandType="StoredProcedure"
        commandText="`InsertLog`"
    >
        <parameter name="machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
        <parameter name="logged"         layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="logLevel"       layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="message"        layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="logger"         layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
        <parameter name="callsite"       layout="${callsite:fileName:true}" />
        <parameter name="exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
        <parameter name="callsiteLineNumber"      layout="${callsite-linenumber}" />
        <parameter name="stackTrace"      layout="${stacktrace}" />
    </target>
```

However, it's giving an error "Could not load file or assembly 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore"

Do I have the wrong dbProvider? Does Nlog not work with Pomelo?

Comment: You are getting the exception, because there is no `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore` assembly (it would be `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`). But AFAIK, there is no support for logging statements directly using EF Core in NLog. Therefore, you cannot use Pomelo, because it is an EF Core provider. However, you should be able to use [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) (the ADO.NET provider Pomelo uses under the hood) if you setup your stored procedure an parameters correctly. E.g. you would use `dbProvider="MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection, MySqlConnector"` in your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed lauxjpn's comment, and it worked. Thanks lauxjpn!